# Magnet pattern for Scala MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, implicit, scala-macros, mongo-scala-driver

The documentation describes using the magnet pattern to get implicit conversion to BSON types. See on this page http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-scala/bson/scala-documents/. I have tried defining an implicit object that extends BsonTransformer, but it fails to find a codec for the type. Am I missing something / has someone got this working? Sample code below, assume the insert method is being called.

```
case class CustomType(specialString: String)

implicit object TransformCustomType extends BsonTransformer[CustomType] {

  def apply(value: CustomType): BsonString = 
      BsonString(value.specialString)
}

lazy val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase(dbName).withCodecRegistry(DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
lazy val testCollection: MongoCollection[CustomType] = db.getCollection[CustomType](collectionName)

def insert: Future[Completed] = testCollection.insertOne(CustomType("a")).toFuture
```

Error -
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.bla.BlaClass$CustomType.

*note that I am aware this can be done with

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[CustomType]))
```

but I am just using this example to ask to learn the magnet pattern for a messier case.

Comment: Can you include the error and the code where you use this encoder?

Comment: thanks, added an example and error @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: This code compiles with mongo scala driver 4.1.1. Which Scala/mongo driver version are you using?

Comment: It fails at runtime.  4.0.1 driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an implicit `BsonTransformer[T]` (instance of [type class](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/#type-classes-in-scala) `BsonTransformer`) in a scope then there are [implicit conversions](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#implicit-conversions)

- `T => CanBeBsonValue` (`CanBeBsonValue` is a wrapper over `BsonValue`),
- `(String, T) => CanBeBsonElement` (`CanBeBsonElement` is a wrapper over `BsonElement`, which is a "tuple" of `String` and `BsonValue`),
- `Iterable[(String, T)] => CanBeBsonElements` (`CanBeBsonElements` is a wrapper over `Iterable[BsonElement]`)

defined in [`BsonMagnets`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/bson/BsonMagnets.scala) (`CanBeBsonValue`, `CanBeBsonElement`, `CanBeBsonElements` are magnets [1](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/) [2](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern)).

Then [`Document`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/scala-2.13+/org/mongodb/scala/bson/collection/immutable/Document.scala) can be created via factory methods

```
def apply(elems: CanBeBsonElement*): Document

def apply(elem: CanBeBsonElements): Document
```

So try

```
val doc = Document("a" -> CustomType("bb"))

val testCollection: MongoCollection[Document] = ???

testCollection.insertOne(doc)
```